# Which tense to use with "whole last year"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, tenses

I would like to say that I worked whole year for my company on one specific project but I am not sure about the tense and word order. I still work for them and had worked before.

My idea is:

> The whole last year I worked / I was working...

or

> For the whole year 2010 I worked...

Is it the correct tense?

Comment: If you are still working for them, your sentence will clearly communicate this by saying: "I have been working for XXX since ...". After **since** just say the exact point of time you started working for this company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tense you should use depends on whether you are still working there, which you don't specify. *I have been working at XYZ for the whole last year* means for the 12 months up to the date of writing.  *I worked there for the whole of last year* (*of* is needed to distinguish '2011' from 'twelve months to date') is equally grammatical, but means (or at least implies) that you no longer do so. ?*I have been working here for the whole of last year* would mean for the whole of 2011, but invites the question 'So what have you been doing since January?'

Comment: Thanks! Well I am still working here. Not sure what did you mean with that January question? I just want to say that during the 2011 I was still working here (I had been working here before) and I still work here now in 2012.

Comment: @Pietro: the third example specifically omits the first part of 2012, but implies that you are working there now, which is confusing at best. You may prefer 'I continued to work there for the whole of 2011' or something similar; as always, more context would provoke better answers.

Comment: Thanks, what about "During last year I have been working on X project". So I cannot say in present perfect that I have been working there all last year till now?

Comment: @Pietro: read my answer again about 'last year' and 'the last year'. I was tactfully indicating that supplemental questions are best handled by editing your question so that it gives more context, and asks what you actually want to know.

Comment: TimLymington: Thanks, I did. Would like to know what about that present perfect.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

> During the year of 2000 I worked as a cow milker.

Comment: You don’t need that *of* there. Nor, for that matter, *cow*.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

> *All of last year, I worked*...

Answer (score 0):

If the project is completed, and the main idea that you are trying to communicate is that you worked on it for a full year (12 months) seeing it to completion then you can use the simple past. To indicate something began in the past and is still continuing, you can use the present perfect or present perfect progressive.  If you want to communicate both ideas, I suggest something like this:

> I have been working for the Acme Corporation since January of 2011. During the year 2011, I worked on and completed Project X.